# Hessian determinant of a function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, partial-derivative, hessian-matrix

I have a function with two variables ($f(x,y)$). Hessian determinant of the function is always equal to zero: $f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}f_{yx}=0 ~~\forall x,y $ and both $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$ are always positive. What can I say about $f$? Is it convex?

Comment: If your matrix is symmetric, then $f_{xx}+f_{yy} = \lambda_1+\lambda_2 = \text{tr}(H)$ and $\det(H) = f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}f_{yx} = 0 = \lambda_1\lambda_2$, therefore one eigenvalue is positive and the other one is zero, hessian is positive semidefinite and your function is indeed convex. It is important that the matrix be symmetric, because we want a positive bilinear form. It's not important that one of eigenspaces is zero, that means the form is degenerate, it's not an isomorphism but it is a positive form. Think of a matrix like $P = a^Ha$ where $a$ is a vector, it is still positive definite

Comment: @K.K.McDonald Right, Thank you so much.